# How to make a rigged object bend when pressed against a surface?

Tags: animation, physics

I have rigged a shoe, which i have animated. When the tip of the shoe hits the ground, i would like it to bend, just as a shoe. How do i go about this?

I assume that i would have yo use some physics.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use Blender's Lattice tool.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html

it allows you to use a lower resolution 'mesh cage' to deform your model. there are two tutorials on the blender wiki, and this youtube link below is a good tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10asQDMhFQw